# How to exclusively split a string?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I split a String in Python3 with logic along the lines of:

"Split the String by any characters that are not these: foo"

Example:

```py
def exclusive_split(text, list_of_characters_to_keep):
    ...
    return result

text = "Hello, this is some random text."
text2 = exclusive_split(text, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''))
print(text)

# Output
# ['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'random', 'text']
```

Comment: Please add sample input/output along with your current Python attempt.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I currently looking at using regex for it, but as of right now, haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Your comment does not address my comment above.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I added sample input/output. I don't have an attempt to provide as of now because I trying to maybe play around with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

def exclusive_split(text):
    return re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', text).split(" ")


text = "Hello, this is some random text."

text2 = exclusive_split(text)

print(text2)
```

I think this is you are looking for

```
# Output: ['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'random', 'text']
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, to make the code a bit more readable you can use "\```python" on  the line above your code and "\```" on  the line below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method to split a string. I hope this will be helpful

```
def exclusive_split(text):
    result=text.split(" ")
    return result

text = "Hello, this is some random text."
text2 = exclusive_split(text)
print(text2)
```

Happy coding:)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if it was possible to split the by anything that is not in a list of characters to include, I have updated my post. Thanks again for the quick reply :D